# Non-domain joined clients unable to query DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2016

I recently added a domain controller with DNS to our domain on a Windows Server 2016 Standard box. I changed the DNS Server from the scope options in DHCP to point to the new domain controller. On our Windows workstations joined to the domain everything works fine, and I confirmed that their DNS server was pointing to the new domain controller. They're able to resolve local and external DNS names.

Non-domain joined clients on the network don't seem to be able to resolve any DNS names. For example, on my iPhone the DNS server is pointing to the new domain controller with DNS, but I'm unable to resolve any internal or external DNS name. I can ping the DNS server from the client. If I change the DNS server back to the old DNS server everything works fine.

Again, windows workstations joined to the domain are behaving exactly as they should, but non-domain joined clients can't resolve any DNS names.

How could I go about debugging the issue?

Comment: From a windows workstation not joined to the domain, if you ping your Active Directory domain name, that does not resolve?

Comment: I was able to ping the Active directory domain name from a windows workstation not joined to the domain. It seems like it's non-windows devices that are having issues.

Comment: It would be simple for you to perform a packet capture on your domain controller to determine if the DNS request is reaching the domain controller from the problem device. If not, the issue is not with your domain controller.

Comment: Please take a deeper look at the dhcp server configuration. Have you got the option 028 set? What's in there?

Comment: Do the non domain joined clients use the domain DNS suffix in their queries? Do they have the domain DNS suffix configured in their TCP/IP properties? If not, then I'd expect this exact behavior. The domain DNS server isn't going to resolve DNS queries for single label names. This only applies to DNS queries for internal host names where the query is for a single label name. It has no bearing on queries for external FQDN's and has no bearing on queries for internal FQDN's.

Comment: So I took Greg's advice and I did a packet capture on the domain controller. I was able to capture some DNS query packets from the device I was testing with. After a couple of minutes I will stop receiving packets from the device. Once I reset the network connection it will work again for a couple of minutes. This is happening on several devices (all iPhones).